# Can't access to Dart VM Service when run FlutterActivity directly in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

I have 2 FlutterActivity:

- MainActivity
- ShareActivity
  I want to debugging both Activity so when I start Activity in Android Studio the logger print `The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:36157/-5agQOsPk_0=/`. But when I start dart devtools to inspect the app it not works.

Sample code:
https://github.com/definev/dart_vm_bug